# Plot Y values against the time grouped by an ID

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, time, series

I want make a time series plot grouped by ID. My dataset has 42 different IDs with 7 different timeframes. The timeframe varies per ID and ranges from 9/2016 to 8/2018. I.e., ID1 can start 10/2016 and end 7/2017 (with 7 rows containing a different date) and ID40 can start 11/2016 and ends 6/2018 (also with 7 rows containing a different date). I try to plot this with the following code

```
p <- ggplot(data = df6, aes(x = START, y = AI, col = ID, group = ID))
p + geom_point(size     = 1.2,
             alpha    = .8) + stat_smooth(aes(group = 1)) + stat_summary(aes(group = 1), geom = 
             "point", fun.y = mean, 
             shape = 17, size = 3) + theme_minimal() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 
             90,  vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

This gives me the following graph:

[image]

As one can see the X-axis is not chronological. I should start at 09/2016 and end at 08/2018 and then correspond with the Y value based on the ID. I got the following dataset:

```
structure(list(ID = c("ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", 
"ID1", "ID10", "ID10", "ID10", "ID10", "ID10", "ID10", "ID10", 
"ID11", "ID11", "ID11", "ID11", "ID11", "ID12"), Time = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "1"), AI = c(0.393672183448241, 0.4876954603533, 
0.411717908455957, 0.309769862660288, 0.149826889496538, 0.2448558592586, 
0.123606753324621, 0.296109333767922, 0.309960002123076, 0.445886231347992, 
0.370013553008003, 0.393414429902431, 0.318940511323733, 0.131112361225666, 
0.31961673567578, 0.227268892979164, 0.433471105477564, 0.207184572401005, 
0.144257239122978, 0.520204263001733), AI_VAR = c(0.154977788020905, 
0.237846862049217, 0.169511636143347, 0.0959573678125739, 0.0224480968162077, 
0.0599543918132674, 0.0152786294674538, 0.0876807375444826, 0.0960752029161373, 
0.198814531305715, 0.136910029409606, 0.154774913655455, 0.101723049763444, 
0.0171904512661696, 0.102154857724042, 0.0516511497159746, 0.187897199283942, 
0.0429254470409874, 0.020810151039384, 0.270612475245176), activity = c(0, 
0.303472222222222, 0.232638888888889, 0.228472222222222, 0.348611111111111, 
0.215972222222222, 0.123611111111111, 0.357638888888889, 0.235416666666667, 
0.233333333333333, 0.2875, 0.353472222222222, 0.356944444444444, 
0.149305555555556, 0.448611111111111, 0.213888888888889, 0.248611111111111, 
0.288888888888889, 0.25625, 0.238888888888889), ZIM_SD = c(0, 
0.148002025121106, 0.095781596758851, 0.0707738088994687, 0.0522313184217097, 
0.0528820640482116, 0.0152791681192935, 0.105900213118389, 0.0729697504998075, 
0.104040120647865, 0.106378896489801, 0.139061072791901, 0.113844043625277, 
0.0195758039329988, 0.143383618921218, 0.0486102909983211, 0.107765733167339, 
0.059853320915846, 0.036965917525263, 0.124271018383747), ZIM_VAR = c(0, 
0.0721799157746582, 0.039434998686126, 0.0219235930627339, 0.00782565597342798, 
0.0129484832318932, 0.00188860836472692, 0.0313580415523671, 
0.0226177040198407, 0.0463900573046668, 0.0393616334552618, 0.0547086326740462, 
0.0363094774850072, 0.00256662987654616, 0.0458278042289798, 
0.0110476070225835, 0.0467133314886466, 0.0124006847007297, 0.00533260120384214, 
0.0646463135307921), CHECK = c(10L, 13L, 11L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 
36L, 36L, 34L, 34L, 32L, 29L, 21L, 28L, 27L, 26L, 25L, 21L, 36L
), BULBAR = c(2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
7L, 6L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), FINE = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 7L
), GROSS = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 
8L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 6L), RESPI = c(6L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 8L, 12L
), GROSS_RENEWD = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L), ACTIVE = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 17L, 15L, 14L, 10L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 13L), NON.ACTIVE = c(8L, 11L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 18L, 18L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 15L, 11L, 23L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 19L, 23L), START = c("09/2016", 
"11/2016", "01/2017", "04/2017", "06/2017", "10/2017", "02/2018", 
"10/2016", "12/2016", "02/2017", "04/2017", "07/2017", "11/2017", 
"04/2018", "10/2016", "12/2016", "02/2017", "04/2017", "07/2017", 
"10/2016"), STOP = c("10/2016", "11/2016", "01/2017", "04/2017", 
"06/2017", "10/2017", "03/2018", "10/2016", "12/2016", "02/2017", 
"04/2017", "07/2017", "11/2017", "04/2018", "10/2016", "12/2016", 
"02/2017", "04/2017", "07/2017", "10/2016")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

**In general I want the column START to start with the begin date and end with the last date when it is plotted**

Answer (score 2):

You should convert your "START" column to a date format. You could use the package `zoo` with the function `as.yearmon` for that. To start the axis with your start date and end it with the end date, you could create a vector of date breaks using the min (start) date and max (end) date. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
df6 <- df6 %>%
  mutate(START = as.Date(as.yearmon(START, format = '%m/%Y'))) 

breaks.vec <- c(min(df6$START),
               seq(from=min(df6$START), to=max(df6$START), by = 'month'))

ggplot(data = df6, aes(x = START, y = AI, col = ID, group = ID)) +
  geom_point(size = 1.2, alpha = .8) + 
  stat_smooth(aes(group = 1)) + 
  stat_summary(aes(group = 1), geom = "point", fun.y = mean, shape = 17, size = 3) + 
  scale_x_date(breaks = breaks.vec, date_labels = "%m/%Y") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,  vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
#> Warning: `fun.y` is deprecated. Use `fun` instead.
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: When I use the code I get the following error: Error in seq.int(r1$mon, 12 * (to0$year - r1$year) + to0$mon, by) : 
'from' must be a finite number

It make the format with %d/%m/%Y in the column instead of %m/%Y

Comment: I omitted some NA values. Now it works. Thanks.